# Cannot able to access class function in different file

Tags: php, html

index.php

```
<?php  include 'Foo.php'; ?>
<div id="middle_containe_cr" style="background-color:#F0F0FF">
<form method="post" action="actionpage.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<table cellspacing="30px" style="padding-left:25%">
<tr>
<td colspan="2" align="center" style="font:caption" > Hi
<form method="post" action="actionpage.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<table cellspacing="30px" style="padding-left:25%">
<tr>
<td colspan="2" align="center" style="font:caption" > Hi
<?php

$blObj=new Foo();
$userDetails=$blObj->SampleFunction($userID);
echo $userDetails->name;
?>

</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="299">UserID</td>
<td width="302"><?php echo $userID; ?></td>
</tr>
```

---

Foo.php

```
include 'Bar.php';
class Foo
{

    public function SampleFunction($userID)
    {
        $userName=null;
        $dalObj=new Bar();
        $userName=$dalObj->SampleFunction($userID);
        return $userName;
    }

}
```

---

Bar.php

```
include ('DataConnection.php');

class Bar
{

    public function SampleFunction($userID)
    {
        $name='';

        $db=DataConnection::DBConnect();
        $stmt=$db->prepare("CALL usp_UserAccountBasicDetails(?)");
        $stmt->bind_param('s',$userID);

        if (!$stmt->execute()) 
            {
                echo "Execute failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
            }
        else
            {
                $result = $stmt->get_result();
                $resultSet = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM);

                $name=$resultSet[1];
                $result->free_result();
            } 

        return $name;

    }

}
```

Hi All I'm facing a issue in above code while I'm Hosting this code in remote server. When I execute my localhost the above code execute successfully without any issues. But if I upload this to remote server the code does not execute after Function calling statement.
It just print  'Hi' (in HTML td content), where as in that i concatenate the php content to get name from db through two classes. None the code below that function calling statement get execute.

Please help me !! Thanks!!

Comment: Any messages in the PHP error log?

Comment: you need to do something like this

class Bar extends DataConnection

then

Class foo extends Bar

Comment: check permission on server for the files...!!

Comment: @Guru : not necessary with PHP!! :)

Comment: When you run `<?php print_r(get_declared_classes()); ?>` do you see PDO, mysqli, etc?

Comment: how about file permission on your server?

Comment: Try out `require_once` instead of `include`. It throws error if required file doesn't exist.

Comment: @Jerdiggity : Ya I can see mysqli class

Comment: @Algorhythm: I tried with required_once also.. Its not working

Comment: @NoobEditor: How can i Check that

Comment: @Barmar:No error message while executing..

Comment: @Hariharasudhan : on you `cpanel` on server...simply right click and check permission...or through unix terminal....do `ls -l filename`!

Comment: @NoobEditor: It is having read permission and I also provide the execute permission.. Still not working..

Comment: @Hariharasudhan :  is the path correct?also check the folder permissions!! :)

Comment: @NoobEditor: Path are all perfect. Checked that too !! No improvements

Comment: are you sure folder permission is 755 and not 777 and file to 644 and no any thing else?

Comment: @NoobEditor: Its in 755 only